# extract just the values from a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataframe. I extracted some values from it using iloc. However, when I tried to list these values it didn't list just the values.

`display(y_values)`

````
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64,
 32    3.4
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64,
 34    4.6
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64,
 12    3.7
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64,
 25    5.2
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64,
 11    4.3
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64,
 17    4.5
 Name: 2000, dtype: float64] ```

I've only wanted the values. So how can I do it?
````

Answer (score 0):

The information is insufficient but try this:

```
y_values = df.iloc[0, :2] # assuming your y_values is this
y_values = list(y_values.values)
print(y_values)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't wrk because it says that list object has no attribute as .values.

Answer (score 0):

`turkey_expendition = education_expendition[education_expendition['country'] == 'Turkey']`

`turkey_all = turkey_expendition.iloc[:1]`

`turkey_all_2000 = turkey_all['2000']`

I've done the above code for these countries and created the following list.

`y_values = [france_all_2000,turkey_all_2000,usa_all_2000,greece_all_2000,poland_all_2000,germany_all_2000,italy_all_2000]`

Any other ideas?